# How to run five agent jobs simultaneously in VSTS (Azure DevOps)?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have created a release pipeline with five agent jobs and I want to start all five jobs at the same time.

example:

[image: vsts]

In example I need to start all agent jobs simultaneously, and execute unique task (wait 10 seconds) at the same time.

Does VSTS (Azure DevOps) have option to do this?

Comment: Why you not put the 5 tasks in one agent job and run the job simultaneously like the answers below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also just use 5 different stages (depending on what exactly it is you're doing). Then you can leverage the full power of the pipeline model, have pre and post stages, whatever you wish. This is as mentioned in the other answers also possible with different agent jobs but this is more straight forward. Also you can easily clone stages.

I'm not sure what it is what you're trying to achieve with waiting for 10 seconds, but this is very easy to do with a PowerShell step. Select the radio button "Inline" and type this:

```
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
```

Example of a pipeline, that might do the simultaneous work that you want, but keep in mind, each agent job (doesn't matter multiple jobs in one stage or multiple single job stages) has to find an agent that is capable, available and idle, otherwise the job(s) will wait in a waiting queue!!!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the release pipeline click on "Agent job", then expand the "Execution plan" and click on "Multi-agent".

[image]

Comment: I try out your approach, but the `Multi-Agent` option only takes a agent job and run the same task on multiple agents (5 in your example). Is it possible to run different task _concurrent_ on multiple agents, without creating a separate stage for it? Why is the behavior of **release pipelines** so different to **build pipelines**. There, each _agent job_ get executed concurrent, why not simply in **release pipelines** too?

Comment: @MarTin I don't think so :/ you can add more phases (each phase = another agent) but I don't know if it will run in parallel

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create 5 stages since for the release pipeline in the Azure devops, jobs in one stage could not be paralleled.[see documents from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops#how-a-parallel-job-is-consumed-by-a-pipeline) 
Or if you want to run the same set of set of tasks on multiple agents, you could use the option **Multi-agent** as shown below.
[ADO Multi-agent option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3WYy.png)

Answer (score -1):

If you want a job to be executed in parallel then choose multi-agent configuration, but if you have 5 (very) different jobs then you can choose "Even if a previous job has failed" from the dropdown "Run this job".

This is by default set to "Only when all previous jobs have succeeded" which means that:

1. All of your 5 jobs will be executed sequentially in the order that you've set them up
2. The chain of jobs will come to a stop as soon as one of the jobs fails

Take note that you can specify individually on what agent queue what job will execute, by default they're all going to the same queue, if you run 5 jobs in parallel on a single queue, then this queue should have 5 agents available and idle to get what you're expecting.

[image]

Comment: sorry, overlooked the middle line in your question. so yes, choose either the one that I've mentioned or choose a custom variable and play around with that, that way you could further customize the behavior of your release

Comment: Is there a way to set this up such that Agent Job B & Agent Job C run in parallel only after Agent Job A succeeds?

Comment: This works for build pipelines, but for some reason this has no effect on release pipelines. I think it's an MS bug.